# Which X-Men story arc shows the team investigating a radio blackspot in China?

Tags: story-identification, comics, marvel

I'm trying to track down a comic book story arc I had one piece from. I remember it had *an* X-Men team in china, with [Armor](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hisako_Ichiki_%28Earth-616%29) on the roster. They'd found a radio blackspot, and went in to investigate. I'd love to know where this so I can pick up from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series is the Astonishing X-men. The run you are looking for is the "Ghost Box" (Issues 25-30).

[image]

From Wikipedia:

> Based in San Francisco, Ellis established the X-Men as protectors of
>   the city. The new team consisted of Cyclops, Emma Frost, Beast,
>   Wolverine and Armor, and later, Storm arrived. The X-Men uncovered a
>   plot of mutant synthesis from an unusual murder. The killer
>   (designated 'X') was located, fixing and restarting the eponymous
>   "ghost box" in a spaceship. X was defeated but killed himself rather
>   than surrender information about his intentions and "the Annex."
>
> The team returned to San Francisco with Suspect X's "mysterious box"
>   (actually a "Ghost Box") in tow and gave it to Hank along with a
>   syringe filled with Suspect X's blood. After analyzing the box and
>   blood, Hank told Scott that after having gone over Suspect X's file
>   there appears to be talk about a secret war between Suspect X's people
>   and the murdered mutant from the beginning of the story arc.
>
> There is also talk about a mysterious place called Tian which is in
>   China and that piques the interest of Wolverine. After analyzing
>   Suspect X's blood, Hank finds out that Suspect X is just a normal
>   mutant but with his X-gene on a different chromosome. Just like the
>   murder victim, Hank believes that Suspect X is a manufactured mutant.
>   Hank wants to bring in Abigail Brand from S.W.O.R.D. in to help
>   investigate this matter, but Scott is against that. In the end,
>   against Scott's wishes, Agent Brand is brought in who lets the X-Men
>   know that the Ghost Box is a dimensional portal between different
>   realities. Hank then concludes that Suspect X is not a manufactured
>   mutant after all; in Suspect X's reality the x-gene is normally
>   located on a different chromosome.
>
> Brand wants to turn this case into a S.W.O.R.D.-only case but Scott
>   counters it. Brand gives Scott and the X-Men time to investigate
>   before she brings in S.W.O.R.D. With the help of Wolverine, the X-Men
>   locate Tian, which is an uncharted area of China that no surveillance
>   or satellite system can get through, not even the Chinese government.
>   The X-Men are able to sneak into Tian and discover the headquarters of
>   a secret group of mutants informally referred to by Hank as the
>   "Chinese X-men." Sadly, they seem to have died because of M-Day's
>   associated effects.